# A virtual function header followed by a statement

Tags: c++

I am not sure of my interpretation of these instructions:

```
virtual int getRadioChannel(RadioRef r) const = 0;
virtual int getNumChannels() = 0;
```

For me, the first one means that a called of the function getRadioChannel returns always 0 and the second one does nothing when the function getNumChannels is called.
Am I right ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Abstract_classes_and_pure_virtual_functions

Comment: "virtual function header" is already the wrong term. What book are you using to learn C++ and the terms used in that context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not right, the `=0` signifies a **pure virtual function**.

That makes the class abstract and forces all non-abstract derived classes to implement the methods marked as pure.

Answer (score 5):

> Am I right ?

No, not at all.

These are declarations of functions that are intended to form, in part, an *interface*.

Read about *pure virtual functions* in [your C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

These are both declaring *pure virtual* functions; functions without definition in the class they are declared in.  Since there are no definitions of the functions, the class cannot be instantiated; only subclasses of the class, which *do* have these functions defined, can.

In the first case, it's also `const` function -- essentially, the you're promising not to modify the object in the body of the function.  (Specifically: the `this` pointer in the function body will be `const`, and the function is callable on `const` objects.)  The second case is just a "normal" pure virtual function declaration.

You can read more about [pure virtual functions here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/126-pure-virtual-functions-abstract-base-classes-and-interface-classes/), and [const functions here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/810-const-class-objects-and-member-functions/).

Answer (score 0):

```
virtual int getRadioChannel(RadioRef r) const { return 0; }
```

This is what a function that always returns 0 would look like. As others have pointed out, equating the function to 0, makes it a [pure virtual function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Abstract_classes_and_pure_virtual_functions).

> A pure virtual function or pure virtual method is a virtual function that is required to be implemented by a derived class, if that class is not abstract. Classes containing pure virtual methods are termed "abstract"; they cannot be instantiated directly. A subclass of an abstract class can only be instantiated directly if all inherited pure virtual methods have been implemented by that class or a parent class.